# How do I find out the problem with a "Bad Request" returned from an ASP.NET Core Web API call?

Tags: asynchronous, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, bad-request

We have a Blazor front end app that uses a C# service layer and repository patterned ASP.NET Core Web API.

When trying to make a `POST` request to one of the controllers, I only get a 400 "Bad Request" returned. I cannot get a breakpoint to hit in the API controller method and I cannot seem to view the request before it is being sent.

I'm using VS 2022

The initial service call:

```
await IssueHoldService.CreateIssueHold(issueHold);
```

The service method:

```
public async Task<Warrant> CreateIssueHold(Warrant warrant)
{   
    var warrantJson = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(warrant), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    string x = warrantJson.ToString();

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/IssueHold", warrantJson);

    Warrant result = null;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Warrant>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    }

    return result;
}
```

This response returns:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcMzIzNjA2XHNvdXJjZVxFZ2lkLlJlY29uXEVnaWQuUmVjb24uQXBpXGFwaVxJc3N1ZUhvbGQ=?=
  Persistent-Auth: true
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 18:11:39 GMT
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}
```

The API controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Warrant warrant)
    {
        if (warrant == null)
            return BadRequest();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        try
        {
            var newId = await _issueHoldRepository.CreateAsync(warrant);
            var createdWarrant = await _issueHoldRepository.GetByIdAsync(newId);
            return Created("warrant", createdWarrant);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

The repository method:

```
public async Task<int> CreateAsync(Warrant entity)
{
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[IssueHold]
                           ([CheckNumber]
                           ,[IssueSuffix]
                           ,[ControlNumber]
                           ,[AgencyNumber]
                           ,[Name]
                           ,[SSN]
                           ,[Addr1]
                           ,[Addr2]
                           ,[City]
                           ,[St]
                           ,[Zip]
                           ,[Reason]
                           ,[DateIssued]
                           ,[IssuedBy]
                           ,[AmountPaid]
                           ,[AmountDue]
                           ,[RefundAmount]
                           ,[ClaimNumber]
                           ,[DateMailed]
                           ,[DateCreated]
                           ,[CreatedBy]
                           ,[PrintIssue]
                           ,[PrintAmount]
                           ,[Beneficiary]
                           ,[WarrantType]
                           ,[Void]
                           ,[DateRequested]
                           ,[OrigCheckNum])
                     OUTPUT Inserted.HoldKey
                     VALUES
                           (@CheckNumber
                           , @IssueSuffix
                           , @ControlNumber
                           , @AgencyNumber
                           , @Name
                           , @SSN
                           , @Addr1
                           , @Addr2
                           , @City
                           , @St
                           , @Zip
                           , @Reason
                           , @DateIssued
                           , @IssuedBy
                           , @AmountPaid
                           , @AmountDue
                           , @RefundAmount
                           , @ClaimNumber
                           , @DateMailed
                           , @DateCreated
                           , @CreatedBy
                           , @PrintIssue
                           , @PrintAmount
                           , @Beneficiary
                           , @WarrantType
                           , @Void
                           , @DateRequested
                           , @OrigCheckNum)";
        try
        {
            using (var connection = CreateConnection())
            {
                return (await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
}
```

How can I view the actual request to see what might be malformed?  I've tried putting a console log in the `!ModelState.IsValid` portion of the API controller but it never logs anything.

Any ideas?

Here is the DB Table where the SQL is trying to insert

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Egid.Recon.Shared.Entities
{
    public class Warrant : EntityBase
    {
        public int HoldKey { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string CheckNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        public string IssueSuffix { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string ControlNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string AgencyNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(60)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(9)]
        public string SSN { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Addr1 { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Addr2 { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        public string St { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public string Reason { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateIssued { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string IssuedBy { get; set; }
        //[RegularExpression(@"^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Amount. Please use the format of XXXX.XX.")]
        public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
        public string AmountPaidDisplay
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0:C2}", AmountPaid); }
        }
        //[RegularExpression(@"^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Amount. Please use the format of XXXX.XX.")]
        public decimal AmountDue { get; set; }
        public string AmountDueDisplay
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0:C2}", RefundAmount); }
        }

        public decimal RefundAmount { get; set; }

        public string RefundAmountDisplay
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0:C2}", RefundAmount); }
        }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateMailed { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public bool PrintIssue { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string PrintAmount { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Beneficiary { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(9)]
        public string WarrantType { get; set; }

        public bool Void { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateRequested { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(9)]
        public string OrigCheckNum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is common if the wrong verb is used or the actual parameters do not match the formal parameters. You are being told that an action expecting this parameter(s) does not exist in the controller. You should be able to see what is being sent over via the F12 tools of the browser or Fiddler or some other http debugger.

Comment: I've added the Warrant Class and the DB table trying to populate.  The Route on the contoller is: [Route("api/[controller]")]

Comment: @RossBush are you saying the JSON getting posted in the body is not properly mapping to the "Warrant" type in the API Controller method?

Comment: @jthorn - I deleted my answer because it was more of a distraction. Is the Warrant object you are sending over an instance of the same class the api is expecting. If varies wildly , you can get a 400.

Comment: @RossBush Yes it is the same.  The Service method receives a Warrant object, JSON serializes it and then posts that to the API.  The API Method attempts to build a Warrant object [From Body]  and insert that into the DB via the Repository.  If I could get a break point to catch in the API or Repository, I could possibly have better luck diagnosing what the actual problem is.  Even if I could see the actual body of the Request I'm sending to the API but I don't seem to be able to do that either.  This is an application I've inherited that was 80% done but no documentation.....

Comment: @HH I cannot see the body using F12.  The service layer is what is making the API call and that exists server-side, not the page itself.  I'm running all of this on localserver however and if I could get the API to catch a break point, I could examine what's happening.  I'm not sure the Void case is any issue.  The database field is named "Void".  I tried moving the !ModelState.IsValid part to the beginning  of the method and even put an "Else{}" on it to log both states, but get no output to the console and the breakpoint does not hit.

Comment: @HH The breakpoint at the first { does not catch so there may be some type of Routing or Binding issue.  That was my first instinct but the Route seems ok and the object type is correct.   I will try pursuing that

Comment: @jthorn - "The service layer is what is making the API call and that exists server-side" - Probably a good time to start logging request/response messages between service boundaries.

Comment: One last recommend. Take the parameter out of the api call altogether, so it is void Create(). If you don't get a breakpoint, then your debugging is not set up correctly or your routing is misconfigured.

Comment: @jthorn You should check there isn't another controller, razor page... that uses the same route.